# Keycloak REST API Unable to Delete client-level roles from user role mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

Hoping someone can help me on this. I've created my own Keycloak Realm, and client. I am using Spring boot and KeycloakRestTemplate from org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.client.KeycloakRestTemplate; to make all my calls.

I've been successful in adding client-level roles to the user role mapping to any given user.

I prefix my URI with /admin/realms/ when using the Keycloak API docs. So far all my requests have worked (getting a list of users from my client, getting a list of users that have a particular client-level role, and even adding client-level roles to a user as described above)

My problem is I cannot delete client-level roles from a user. I've looked at the keycloak docs and it looks like I've followed everything correctly. I also made sure the user had applicable client roles available to be deleted. I really appreciate any comments or help given!!

https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/14.0/rest-api/index.html

"Delete client-level roles from user role mapping
DELETE /{realm}/users/{id}/role-mappings/clients/{client}"

```html
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.client.KeycloakRestTemplate;

.
.
.


    @Autowired
        private KeycloakRestTemplate restTemplate;
.
.
.
.
.


UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(keycloakServerUrl + "/admin/realms/"+keycloakRealm+"/users/"+userId+"/role-mappings/clients/"+keycloakClientId);

this.restTemplate.postForEntity(builder.toUriString(), rolesList, List.class);  // this works! Note: rolesList is an List<RoleRepresentation> object

.
.
.

this.restTemplate.delete(builder.toUriString(), rolesList); // Does not work!
```

URI: http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:8180/auth/admin/realms/VLS/users/2144cc43-59f4-4406-9527-2a59ee0c3751/role-mappings/clients/53e659e1-7cef-4dbb-8cdd-b786ca3a44a4

Error when calling Delete API: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$UnsupportedMediaType: 415 Unsupported Media Type: [{"error":"RESTEASY003065: Cannot consume content type"}]

Edit 1: I have also given myself ALL available roles from all clients as a precaution beforehand. I understand some roles are needed to perform certain tasks even through the API. I've taken this into account.

Comment: Just as a quick idea, have you thought about setting the application/json value as content type?

Comment: Thank you for your response! @rimesc resolved my problem below. 

According to the KeycloakRestTemplate class all of it's methods are inherited from Spring's RestTemplate and 

"The main advantage to using this class over Spring's <code>RestTemplate</code> is that authentication is handled automatically when both the service making the API call and the service being called are protected by Keycloak authentication."

so i believe this class automatically appends the application/json header with every request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KeycloakRestTemplate` [appears to inherit](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/adapters/oidc/spring-security/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/springsecurity/client/KeycloakRestTemplate.java) all of its methods directly from Spring’s `RestTemplate`.  According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#delete-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) for that class, the second argument to `delete` isn’t a request body, as I think you’re intending.  Rather, it’s a vararg of objects used to expand template variables in the URI.

There doesn’t appear to be a variant of the `delete` method that allows you to supply a body, so you’ll probably need to use one of the variants of the `execute` or `exchange` methods that accepts an HTTP method and a request entity instead.  In fact, the `RestTemplate` API makes this quite difficult to do, because it’s generally assumed that `DELETE` requests don’t have bodies.

Comment: Thank you so much!! You hit the nail on the head :) I went with your advice and used the exchange method since I had a request body for my delete request and it went through successfully! `HttpEntity<List<RoleRepresentation>> request = new HttpEntity<List<RoleRepresentation>>(deleteRolesList); this.restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.DELETE, request, List.class); `

Answer (score 0):

The alternate way to interact with Keycloak can be using the [keycloak starter dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-spring-boot-starter) and the [keycloak admin client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-admin-client).

1. Add the dependencies mentioned above.
2. Configure the Keycloak admin user.

   ```
   public Keycloak getAdminKeycloakUser() {
   return KeycloakBuilder.builder()
       .serverUrl(keycloakAuthUrl)
       .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD)
       .realm(masterRealm).clientId(masterClient)
       .username(adminUsername).password(adminPassword)
       .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(10).build())
       .build();
   }
   ```

With this admin user we can delete the client user along with other actions.

```
getAdminKeycloakUser().realm(realm).clients().roles().deleteRole(roleName);
```